# How to change x, y, z axis in 3mpl_toolkits.mplot3d python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Could you help me with adjusting the axis in the 3d plot? I can't change these three axix separately. I hope that the dots are in the center of the plot. Thanks!

'''

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def gen_2d_dome(n_layers=6):
    #T = [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
    #R = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
    T = [1] + [(x+1)*10 for x in range(n_layers-1)]
    TT = [1] + [(x+1)*10 for x in range(n_layers-1)]
    R = [0.0] + [(x+1)*0.1 for x in range(n_layers-1)]

    T = [int(np.ceil(x*0.6)) for x in T]
    TT = [int(np.ceil(x*0.6)) for x in TT]
    R = [x*20 for x in R]

     def rtpairs(r, n, nn): 
         for i in range(len(r)):
           for j in range(n[I]):
              for k in range(nn[I]):
                  yield r[i]*1, j*(2 * np.pi / n[i]),k*(1 * np.pi / nn[I])
   points, ppoints = [], []
   for r, t, tt in rtpairs(R, T, TT):
       x, y,z = r * np.sin(tt)*np.cos(t), r *np.sin(tt)*np.sin(t),r*np.cos(tt)
        if y>=-0 and z>=0:
           ppoints.append([r,t,tt])
           points.append([x,y,z])
  points = np.array([[x/12*255+255,y/12*255+255,z/12*255+255] for x, y,z in points])
 
return points

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
#ax.set_xlim3d(1,200)
ax.scatter(g[:, 0], g[:, 1], g[:, 2])
#ax.plot(g[:, 0], g[:, 1], g[:, 2])
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,6)
plt.show()
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ax.set_xlim`, `ax.set_ylim`, `ax.set_zlim`:

```py
g = gen_2d_dome()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(g[:, 0], g[:, 1], g[:, 2])
ax.set_xlim(g[:, 0].min(), g[:, 0].max())
ax.set_ylim(g[:, 1].min(), g[:, 1].max())
ax.set_zlim(g[:, 2].min(), g[:, 2].max())
plt.show()
```